# How Can I Merge Geocoded Addresses With a Shapefile and Export One Table?

Tags: qgis, export, geocoding

I currently have two layers in my QGIS (v1.7.3 for Mac) project -- one being a Pennsylvania State House shapefile and the other being 166 geocoded addresses (for which I used 'Add Text Delimited Layer' with XY latitude and longitude columns as coordinates). The mapping of these two worked great:

[image: AddressesWithStateHouseShapefile]

But is there a way for me to get the data *out* of QGIS and back into an Excel file, with regards to which state house district each geocoded address falls into?

Ideally, the data would come out similar to:

```
    Latitude Longitude District
    40.14524 -75.21491 131
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Vector>>>Data Management tools>>>Join Attributes by location[image]

I think this may help you.

Comment: Thanks, this (http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php) seemed like the best thing I could find on how to make 'Join Attributes By Location' work how I need it -- but I don't quite understand the output shapefile part of it.